# How do you compile your own kernel on a RHEL6 system?

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, compiling

In RHEL6, the kernel is 2.6.32. What is the procedure to compile your own kernel?

Comment: Why do you need your own kernel? What are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 5):

I would take a look a these CentOS howtos to get started. CentOS is the community edition of RHEL. It's pretty much identical to what Red Hat provides in their version of the distro.

- [I Need to Build a Custom Kernel](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel)
- [I Need the Kernel Source](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source)
- [How To Compile A Kernel - The CentOS Way](http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_centos)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can i go ahead with the same thing or i have to change any commands accordingly?

Comment: The commands should all be the same.

Comment: But note that newer kernels might require changes in compiler, glibc, and assorted userland utilities.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a newer kernel, elrepo might be helpful and save you the grief:

http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php

http://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el6/

Don't expect it to necessarily be flawless.  I tried one of the newer kernels on a CentOS 5 machine recently, for some reason the NFS server would not start.  I ended up digging-in and rebuilt that server in CentOS 7.